# ID ,которое я вывел из базы данных не приравнивается с ID клиента, хотя должно

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

**основной код:**

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startswith='read '))
async def process_callback_button1(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    ID = callback.data.replace('read ', '')
    #await callback.answer(f'вывод ID: /{ID}')
    #выводит ID в правильном виде
    if ID == callback.from_user.id:
        await callback.answer(f'вы уже зарегистрированы', show_alert=True)
    if ID != callback.from_user.id:
        await add_ID(callback.from_user.id)
        await callback.answer(f'User ВЫ зарегистрированы', show_alert=True)
    else:
        await callback.answer('Непредвиденная ошибка')

    


@dp.message_handler(commands=['Регистрирование'])
async def register(message:types.Message):
    read = await read_ID()
    for ret in read:
        if ret == message.from_user.id:
            await message.answer('нажмите на кнопку ниже\/', reply_markup= InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Регистрация', callback_data=f'read {ret}')))
    else:
        await message.answer('нажмите на кнопку ниже\/', reply_markup= InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Регистрация', callback_data=f'read 123')))
```

**код с созданием и выводом данных в базе данных:**

```
import sqlite3 as sq

def sql_start2():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('Waurma_client_id.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base #2 connected OK')

    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list_id (id TEXT)')
    base.commit()

async def add_ID(args):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO list_id VALUES (?)', (args,))
    base.commit()

async def read_ID():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM list_id')
```

**вот что выходит:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если вывести в консоль оба значения, что будет?)

Comment: В `ret` у вас наверняка кортеж из порядкового номера записи и собственно поля базы `ID`. Нужно этот `ID` ещё из кортежа достать, прежде чем сравнивать.

Comment: хаха, а как вывести в консоль эти данные)

Comment: да,  я пробовал вытащить из кортежа и потом выводил значение в тг и там без каких либо символов выводилось ID, но все равно срабатывало одно и тоже условие

Comment: Ну как вывести, инструкцией `print`.